# What is the name of my town?

Tags: riddle

My town has thirteen buildings.
Its name has four letters.
Exactly six roads leave the town.
Only one leads to my twin town.
The other five roads are dead ends.
Four of them are three blocks long.
One of them is two blocks long.
Walk carefully in the dead end cul-de-sacs,
Since sharp objects are hidden there.
I love my town, despite the lines
Nearly everywhere you go.
Whenever something spectacular happens,
We have many meetings with our twin town.

**What is the name of my town?**

Comment: Your profile says Atlanta. :-P

Comment: @DavidRicherby haha! yep you got me there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I think the name of the town is palm

Explanation

> The thirteen buildings are the 5 metacarpals and 8 carpal bones
> Four letters in the word palm
> six roads, five being fingers, one being the arm
> four of the fingers have three knuckles and the thumb has two
> sharp objects are likely nails (fingernails- thanks Bailey M)
> Palms have lines all across them
> You clap with both hands when you enjoy something like a performance

Comment: I'm guessing the sharp objects are fingernails.

Comment: The meetings with our twin town is what made me think of it. Also good call @BaileyM.

Comment: You may wish to mark the answer as "accepted", so other users know that the puzzle has been solved, and that this is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: @fond42518 there ya go